# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object error in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Self join in Eloquent in `category` Model

```
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
 }
```

In blade file:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $category->parent }}</td> // error in this line
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I do this, it shows:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mobile",
    "description": null,
    "image": null,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

When I change `<td>{{ $category->parent }}</td>` to `<td>{{ $category->parent->name }}</td>`, it shows error like:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\laravel-project\laravel_ecommerce\resources\views\admin\pages\category\index.blade.php)

How can I access `$category->parent->name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent has no child, then you will get this error. The below example will throw `No Child` as output  if the parent object is empty :

```
{{ $category->parent->name ??  'No Child' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your getting this  because of hasMany relationship relationship like this.

```
{{$category->parent?$category->parent->name:"Some other message"}}
```